# WinError2 in JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am getting the following error with pip in Jupyter

pip

```
 FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
    ----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('pip', '')
    
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2294, in InteractiveShell.run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
       2292     kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
       2293 with self.builtin_trap:
    -> 2294     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
       2295 return result
    
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:75, in PackagingMagics.pip(self, line)
         72 else:
         73     python = shlex.quote(python)
    ---> 75 self.shell.system(" ".join([python, "-m", "pip", line]))
         77 print("Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.")
    
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py:634, in ZMQInteractiveShell.system_piped(self, cmd)
        632         if path is not None:
        633             cmd = 'pushd %s &&%s' % (path, cmd)
    --> 634         self.user_ns['_exit_code'] = system(cmd)
        635 else:
        636     self.user_ns['_exit_code'] = system(self.var_expand(cmd, depth=1))
    
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\_process_win32.py:124, in system(cmd)
        122 if path is not None:
        123     cmd = '"pushd %s &&"%s' % (path, cmd)
    --> 124 return process_handler(cmd, _system_body)
    
    File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\_process_common.py:77, in process_handler(cmd, callback, stderr)
         75 if shell and os.name == 'posix' and 'SHELL' in os.environ:
         76     executable = os.environ['SHELL']
    ---> 77 p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=shell,
         78                      executable=executable,
         79                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
         80                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
         81                      stderr=stderr,
         82                      close_fds=close_fds)
         84 try:
         85     out = callback(p)
    
    File ~\subprocess.py:858, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
        854         if self.text_mode:
        855             self.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stderr,
        856                     encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
    --> 858     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        859                         pass_fds, cwd, env,
        860                         startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
        861                         p2cread, p2cwrite,
        862                         c2pread, c2pwrite,
        863                         errread, errwrite,
        864                         restore_signals, start_new_session)
        865 except:
        866     # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
        867     for f in filter(None, (self.stdin, self.stdout, self.stderr)):
    
    File ~\subprocess.py:1311, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
       1309 # Start the process
       1310 try:
    -> 1311     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
       1312                              # no special security
       1313                              None, None,
       1314                              int(not close_fds),
       1315                              creationflags,
       1316                              env,
       1317                              cwd,
       1318                              startupinfo)
       1319 finally:
       1320     # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe
       1321     # handles that only the child should have open.  You need
       (...)
       1324     # pipe will not close when the child process exits and the
       1325     # ReadFile will hang.
       1326     self._close_pipe_fds(p2cread, p2cwrite,
       1327                          c2pread, c2pwrite,
       1328                          errread, errwrite)
    
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This is the error I am getting. I removed the anaconda and deleted all the folders and reinstalled it. Still the problem persists. Not able to fix it. I looked in Stack overflow for a solution and tried many thing nothing is working. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you create a virtual environment and activate it first?

Comment: I am not running in virtual environment. I am having only one kernel. Python 3 (ipykernel)

Comment: Did you run something like `pip install package_name`? What was the exact `pip` magic you executed?

Comment: yes.. for example pip install numpy I get this error for all pip commands regardless of the package I get this error. I tried many things like deleting all the Anaconda folders and reinstaling Anaconda, adding the path in python..nothing seems to work..